# implement minimumfontsize in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the minimumfontsize property in android. This is common to the ios sdk. Since it is not presently available in android I was wondering if anyone can help me with a similar implementation in android?

To be more specific, I am trying to implement this property for the TextViewUI in android.Hence I basically need to implement it for this widget.

These are the ios specs of this feature:
"When drawing text that might not fit within the bounding rectangle of the label, you can use this property to prevent the receiver from reducing the font size to the point where it is no longer legible.

The default value for this property is 0.0. If you enable font adjustment for the label, you should always increase this value. This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you intend to do with the code, there isn't much help to be had. The closest thing to what you describe in android is setting device independent pixels (`android:textSize="30dp"`), which ensure that however big (or small) the text looks on your handset, it will look pretty much just like that on all other handsets, at least those of the same size/density. See [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textSize) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the specifics, thanks.

Comment: hrm i meant more of like what do you need android to do that ios was doing with `miniumumfontsize`

Comment: its really simple actually.for the minimumfontsize in ios, when drawing text that might not fit within the bounding rectangle of the label, you can use this property to prevent the receiver from reducing the font size to the point where it is no longer legible..therefore how can I implement this with the TextView?

Comment: ah i see, well to the best of my knowledge, the easiest way to do that is just trial and error using `android:textSize="#dp"` Once it looks good on your handset/emulator, it should look good/the same on all other handsets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at it and give a heads up!!

Comment: did that do what you needed or do you need more help?

Comment: hooraygradschool, this only made things slightly worse, Please help!!

Comment: haha ok, well why don't you add your code or more information to your question and ill see what i can do

Comment: hooraygradschool, I have posted the info. from the ios specs. Maybe they can give an idea of how to approach this:

Comment: hooraygradschool, thanks for all the insight. I do agree that android does not have thisn implementation. The purpose of this feature when set by the user is to perform the functionality its intended for as it is used in the iphone. So,do you think you could help?

Comment: yes, probably, depending on the aim of your application, if you could tell me more about what it was trying to do then i could probably tell you how android does it